# Windows Server as a Domain Controller without a static IP

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

I'm quite new to networking with Windows Server so please bear with me. I have Windows 2008 Server machine that I want to use a a domain controller. I'm currently in a Regus shared office and we're using their network for internet. Their network uses DHCP to assign IP addresses so the Windows Server can't have a static IP which causes problems with it being a domain controller.

Is there a way I can still make the domain controller work with a dynamic IP address? I'm using the Windows Server for file services, print services and active directory.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: If this is something that you can't change then ask the people who manage the DHCP server to create a DHCP reservation for the Domain Controller. That way it will always get the same ip address from the DHCP server. You'll also need them to set the DHCP options to assign the Domain Controller ip address as the DNS server for your domain clients.

Comment: I feel that you would perhaps be better off created an isolated network that hangs off the parent network (with a bit of NAT), as you're going to be spinning up a bit of infrastructure, and you would likely benefit from the isolation (particularly as you start playing with things like Dynamic DNS etc.)

Comment: Yeah, what Cameron said - put a router in between the Regus network and your internal.  Regus tech can also arrange a public IP to be forwarded if required.  OTOH, if you're this green, why bother with the server setup?  Why you need file, print, AD etc?

Comment: @CameronKerr that sounds like a good plan, i'll look into that Thanks